# Нужна ли здесь запятая, чтобы обособить оборот с "благодаря"?

Tags: пунктуация

Но цех был использован под продукцию текущего плана, а секционные передачи успешно пробили себе дорогу самостоятельно (,) благодаря собственным техническим преимуществам, и пошли своим ходом.

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит как уточнение, запятую лучше поставить. А если нет, то и второй тоже нет.

Как могут передачи идти своим ходом... Пробивать дорогу – уж ладно...

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в таких условиях запятая не ставится, поскольку "благодаря" является обычным предлогом (сравни "пробили дорогу благодаря собственным преимуществам"). Но в более редких случаях, когда оборот, начинающийся с "благодаря", в речи интонационно обособляется и тем самым рассматривается как уточнение, запятую нужно ставить.